# Expand cftextarea on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, coldfusion

Ok, I'm still fairly new to coldfusion (and StackOverflow) and need some help. So I have a cfquery that will be pulling values from a database and outputting them to a cftextarea. Each value returned from the database will have its own cftextarea.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function expand(){
if (document.getElementById("report").style.width == "1000px"){
document.getElementById("report").style.width = "222.5px";
document.getElementById("report").rows = "1";
}
else{
document.getElementById("report").style.width = "1000px";
document.getElementById("report").rows = "15";
}}
</script>


<cfquery name="getvalues">
SELECT * FROM STUDENT
</cfquery>

<cfset noVals = '#getvalues.recordCount#'>

<cfform>
<!--- find number returned from query, loop number of times, creating a new text area and checkbox each time ---->
<cfloop query="getvalues" startRow=1 endRow="#noVals#">

<cfinput type="checkbox" name="selectedReport">

<cftextarea name="report" rows="1" cols="25">
<cfoutput>
SID: #SID#
GRADE: #GRADE#
FINAL SCORE: #FINAL#
</cfoutput>
</cftextarea>

<img src="assets/images/expand.png" width="35" height="35" style="vertical-align: top;" onclick="expand();">
<br>
</cfloop>

</cfform>
```

I need to know how to expand these cftextareas (preferably with javascript) by clicking on the image beside them. If the cftextarea is its original size, I would like it to expand. If it is expanded, I would like it to shrink back to default size. Any help would be greatly appreciated, the only thing I've managed to do so far is expand and shrink the top cftextarea.

Comment: You have no element with an ID `report`, so your JavaScript won't do anything as it stands. You'll need `<cftextarea id="report" name="report" rows="1" cols="25">`

Comment: I would highly suggest dropping the ColdFusion specific tags and using html, textarea, etc

Comment: Also, textarea's are more suitable when *editing* data. If that is what this form is designed to do, it would be better to use separate fields for each of the three values. Side note, the cfloop looks overly complicated. To output all records in the query, just use `<cfoutput query="yourQuery">.. do stuff here ..</cfoutput>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have ID on element unless you want to write selectors based on name attributes. As mentioned by SleepyFox89 you need to have different names for each textArea. Making it dynamic is pretty easy as you are already inside a loop so just use the SID (or any other unique column) and use it to create dynamic names for the fields.

The `expand()` function you wrote needs to point to that specific textArea for which the 'Expand' Image was clicked. So you need to have an attribute which you'll have to pass from call inside the onclick event.

Here is the working solution (Updated):

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function expand(reportTextId){
   if (document.getElementById(reportTextId).style.width == "1000px"){
      document.getElementById(reportTextId).style.width = "222.5px";
      document.getElementById(reportTextId).rows = "1";
   }
   else{
      document.getElementById(reportTextId).style.width = "1000px";
      document.getElementById(reportTextId).rows = "15";
   }
}
</script>

<!--- query to fetch student records --->
<cfquery name="getvalues">
   SELECT * FROM STUDENT
</cfquery>

<cfform>    
   <!--- find number returned from query, loop number of times, creating a new text area and checkbox each time ---->
   <cfoutput query="getvalues">
      <cfinput type="checkbox" name="selectedReport#getvalues.SID#" id="chkSelectReport#getvalues.SID#">

      <cftextarea name="report#getvalues.SID#" id="report#getvalues.SID#" rows="1" cols="25">
      SID: #SID#
      GRADE: #GRADE#
      FINAL SCORE: #FINAL#
      </cftextarea>

      <img src="assets/images/expand.png" width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align: top;" onclick="expand('report#getvalues.SID#');">
      <br>
   </cfoutput>    
</cfform>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Since they are new to CF, a few notes about style A) no need to capture results of things like QuerySetCell and QueryAddRow if they are never used.  B) If the intent is to output all records in the query, no need for the nested cfloop/cfoutput. Just use `<cfoutput query="...">` C) The `noVals ` variable is not really needed, but if it were, no need for quotes or pound signs around `#getvalues.recordCount#` D) Strictly a matter of preference, but it is cleaner to keep the query code and output code (JS/HTML) separate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Leigh. I tried to preserve the original code written by Brandoonjen. I have updated the code.

Comment: Yes, preserving code (so the asker can understand) while trying to steer them towards best practices is balance :-) @brandoonjen - I second Matt's suggestion for switching to plain html controls instead of the cfform controls. Reason being the CF versions are outdated and notoriously buggy.

Comment: I too prefer plain html control over cfform for the same reason.

Comment: Also, as far as controls go, I've decided to switch over to plain html controls as suggested.  Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 1):

This is a front-end question so I would say the fact that ColdFusion is creating those text areas is not particularly relevant.

I would give each textarea a unique ID so that it can easily be targetted by the script (and debugging is easier)... no doubt you have a primary key from the query that would be ideal.

Set the onClick event of the image to a script that targets the particular textarea and adjusts the size.

There are a number of ways you can track the expanded/standed property for each such as js variables and hidden inputs.